# null in preg_replace replacement attribute

Tags: php, regex, null

I built a google currency converter,but i didn't understand this part of code

```
$converted_amount = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]);
```

what is the job of this pattern,and what is null means here?

full code:

```
$amount = urlencode($_POST['amount']);
            $from_Currency = urlencode($_POST['from']);
            $to_Currency = urlencode($_POST['to']);
            $get = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency");
            $get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get);
            $get = explode("</span>",$get[1]);
            print_r($get);
            $converted_amount = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]);
```

Comment: You can find an explanation of `preg_replace` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

While what Nicolas Maltais wrote is basically true, it is a bit unclear.

- *`[^0-9\.]` … will only match one character.* - True, however, [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) replaces all the matches, since there's no *limit* specified, thus removing all other characters from the string.
- *`null` means replace with an empty string* - seems true, however, is not documented in the [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) manual. Only after quite some searching I found hints on the **Strings** page, section [**Converting to string**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting):

  > String conversion is automatically done in the scope of an
  >   expression where a string is needed. … **`NULL`** is always converted to an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

`[^0-9\.]` means any character but digits `0123456789` and `.`. This will only match one character. `null` means replace with an empty string, delete it in other words. Next time you can do a simple search on Google and find the same information.